# Comparing mutex implementations for async JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, mutex

I've found somewhere implementation of the mutex pattern in JavaScript that works well but it looks really complex. Even, though I understand mutex pattern I don't know why promises in some places are being used in a given way. But about that in a moment. I was playing around with it and I've created my own implementation that is much easier to understand and has less code. Here is project: https://codesandbox.io/s/mutex-2e014

You have there 3 implementations of the mutex pattern. Mutex 0 and 1 is the same version with this difference, that in the version 1, I've simplified code by taking advantage of arrow functions and being able to access this from the parent context. So overall they are the same solutions. My solution is Mutex 2.

You can test code by opening console and clicking buttons from 0 to 2. You can see that each asynchronous action takes 1 second and it will always execute operations in proper order and wait for the previous task to finish. It works the same way in all versions. Also when you hold the SHIFT key, when pressing buttons it will throw an exception and that part is also working the same in all versions. Next thing, I had to compare is return value and that's not different. So my questions is why is it so complex in the first 2 solutions? Am I missing something? Does it really work the same way?

Now the question about the promise usage that I don't understand. In the `Mutex1.ts` file in line 7, we have `return new Promise(resolve);`. We’re passing resolve from the parent promise as the first argument of the Promise constructor which is executor. And from what I read executors are being invoked just before promise creation. In this case, thanks to that we have access to the `unlock` function in the `run` method but I don’t know how it’s possible that `this.lock` returns function. Probably, I don't know promises well enough. Any ideas?

**Mutex 0**

```
export default class MutexA {
  private mutex = Promise.resolve();

  lock() {
    let begin = unlock => {};

    this.mutex = this.mutex.then(() => {
      return new Promise(begin);
    });

    return new Promise(res => {
      begin = res;
    });
  }

  async run(fn) {
    const unlock = await this.lock();
    try {
      return await Promise.resolve(fn());
    } finally {
      unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

**Mutex 1**

```
export default class MutexB {
  private mutex = Promise.resolve();

  lock() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.mutex = this.mutex.then(() => {
        return new Promise(resolve);
      });
    });
  }

  async run(fn) {
    const unlock = await this.lock();
    try {
      return await fn();
    } finally {
      unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

**Mutex 2**

```
export default class MutexC {
  private mutex = Promise.resolve();

  async run(fn) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.mutex = this.mutex.then(async () => {
        try {
          resolve(await fn());
        } catch (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you post the code in the question, it's not like there's very much of it

Comment: @Bravo yep, right good idea. Updated